# Is there a way to trigger a child plan in Bamboo and pass it information like a version number?

Tags: bamboo, thoughtworks-go

We're using [Go.Cd](https://www.gocd.org/) and transitioning to [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo).

One of the features we use in Go.Cd is [value stream maps](https://docs.gocd.org/current/navigation/value_stream_map.html). This enables triggering another pipeline and passing information (and build artifacts) to the downstream pipeline.

This is valuable when an upstream build has a particular version number, and you want to pass that version number to the downstream build.

I want to replicate this setup in Bamboo (without a plugin).

My question is: **Is there a way to trigger a child plan in Bamboo and pass it information like a version number?**

Answer (score 2):

This has three steps.

1. Use a [parent plan/child plan](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/setting-up-plan-build-dependencies-289276887.html) to setup the relationship.
2. Using the artifacts tab, setup [shared artifacts](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/sharing-artifacts-359400060.html) to transfer files of one plan to another.

3a. At the end of the parent build, dump the environment variables to a file

```
env > env.txt
```

3b. Setup (using the artifacts tab) an artifact selector that picks this up.

3c. Setup a fetch for this artifact from the shared artifacts in the child plan.

3d. Using the [Inject Variables task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-a-variables-task-687213475.html) - read the `env.txt` file you have transferred over. Now your build number from the original pipeline is now available in this downstream pipeline. (Just like Go.Cd).